# How to pass 2 parameter from gridView to javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

May i know how to pass more than one parameter to the javascript? In my code, a new window will open after i click on a link inside a gridview. The first parameter(ID) can be successfully but i not sure how to pass in the second parameter(Name). The following code is how i try to pass the params to the javascript

```
 function OpenWin(id, name) {
        window.open("JHProducts.asp?ID=" + id + "&Name=" + name");
 }


<asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
         <a onclick='<%# String.Format("javascript:OpenWin(""{0}"");", Eval("ID"), Eval("Name"))%>' href="javascript:void(0);" style="cursor:Pointer; color: #0000CC;" >Show Details</a> 
      </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: You would be much better off adding a Hyperlink field if all you want to do is open another page : `<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ID,Name" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="JHProducts.asp?ID={0}&amp;Name={1}" />`

Comment: @Nunners , I think you'll need to add Target attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it this or I haven't understood correctly ?

```
<a onclick='<%# String.Format("javascript:OpenWin('{0}','{1}');", Eval("ID"), Eval("Name"))%>' href="javascript:void(0);" style="cursor:Pointer; color: #0000CC;" >Show Details</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<a onclick='javascript:Open(<%# Eval("DocTypeCode") %>)" >A_<%# Eval("Id") %></a>
```